# Cypress + Azure pipeline + "hover" breakpoint = hover breakpoint always reached/active

Tags: azure-devops, hover, breakpoints, cypress

## Description:

We are working on Cypress solution to test criticals functionals paths of a Website. We are using Azure DevOps to launch Cypress (Azure pipelines).
The website is responsive with 2 breakpoints. The first one is a resolution screen breakpoint and the second one detect if propertie "hover" is active or not. Thanks to the last one, we can detect if the device is a touch screen.

The problem is that Cypress launched by Azure test each time (no matter resolution configure in Cypress & no matter browser used) the website in tablet mode.

NB : Cypress launched in a local machine works fine

---

## Question:

We wish that Cypress in Azure test website in desktop mode.

**Something to configure in Azure to allow Cypress to work fine ?**

---

## Tests perform

- To launch Cypress + Chrome/Electron in headless/headed mod
- To launch Cypress with specific viewport (cy.viewport) and specific User agent
- To launch Cypress in console mod
- To specify a resolution for the virtual screen's pipeline => pipeline doesn't need any screen to work...

---

## Versions use

Azure + Cypress 3.8.3 (with cucumber & NTLM)

Comment: How about configure the viewport size with [cy.viewport](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html) or launch Cypress via module API:https://maximilianschmitt.me/posts/cypress-testing-mobile-tablet-desktop/

Comment: Thanks @LeoLiu-MSFT for comment. Unfortunately, "viewport" and "user agent" don't solve my problem. The problem is the detection of touch screen. The website considers that the web browser (via cypress Azure) is launched on a touch screen.
No solution except to modify breakpoint "hover" in web site ?